# Cannot get the date from jquery datepicker with knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jquery-ui-datepicker

My input:

```
<input type="text" id="date_from" name="datefrom" data-bind="value: date_from" class="form-control date-picker" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" tabindex="2"/>
```

my js file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   ko.applyBindings(new BookingsGetAll(), document.getElementById("BookingHistory"));
   CreateDatePickers();
})

function CreateDatePickers() {
   $('.date-picker').datepicker({
       autoclose: true,
       format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'.toLowerCase(),
       clearBtn: true
   });
}


function BookingsGetAll() {
   var self = this;

   self.date_from = ko.observable("2015-03-05");
}
```

I also have a button which on click does `console.log(self.date_from);`

But it returns me some function. How can I get the value so later I can do ajax with the date and get back the data I need.

Comment: @Denisx that's how knockout works, to access observable value just call that function `console.log(self.date_from());` if you want to change that later on you have to use function again: `self.date_from('2017-05-09');`

Comment: @nizzik ah, this is what i needed. Im noob to knockout, thanks!